# Actividad del Sitio

Tags: discusión

De acuerdo a http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/161411/site-activity-and-votegraph?Weeks=12, en las últimas 12 semanas está ocurriendo un tendencia a la alza en el número de comentarios y en los últimos días se han incrementado los votos en las preguntas.

En lo personal he observado mayor actividad en [google-apps-script](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script). ¿Alguno ha observado un incremento en actividad en otras etiquetas?

[image: Actividad del sitio en las últimas 12 semanas]

Comment: Todos los gráficos están creciendo, eso significa que estamos creciendo :D

Comment: @Ruben También he notado que estamos creciendo pero falta analizar un poco más las etiquetas individualmente para ver si encontramos un patrón de crecimiento.

Answer (score 1):

Gráfico comparación de actividad de etiquetas en Stack Overflow en Español con el mayor número de preguntas.

Tomado de http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/310130/compare-tag-activity?Tag1=java&Tag2=javascript&Tag3=android&Tag4=php&Tag5=c%23&Tag6=jquery&Tag7=python&Tag8=html&Tag9=mysql&Tag10=angularjs#graph

[image: Actividad de las 10 etiquetas con mayor número de preguntas]